# Passing String Values in Visual Basic

Tags: string, function, basic

I'm having trouble trying to pass values that are of the string data type.

What can I do to fix this?

Sender:

```
Private Sub verButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles verButton.Click
        If chkauth.auth(csBox.Text, pwBox.Text) Then
            mainForm.Enabled = True
            infoLbl.Visible = False
        Else
            infoLbl.Visible = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

Recipient:

```
Public Function auth(ByVal cs As String, ByVal pw As String)
        Select Case cs
            Case "Chauix"
                If pw = "ihartcha" Then
                    MsgBox("Authentication successful!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success")
                    Return True
                Else
                    Return False

                End If

            Case "Brink"
                If pw = "Jesusismylife" Then
                    MsgBox("Authentication successful!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success")
                    Return True
                Else
                    Return False

                End If

            Case Else
                Return False

        End Select

    End Function
```

It always results in an error when I try to execute the event that causes it.

Comment: Is this VB6 or VB.NET?

Comment: just wondering, if you are using your actual username and password? you might want to change those in your example if you are :)

Comment: Nah. They aren't. They're just samples to show my classmates :D

Answer (score 0):

not sure what error you are getting, please advise.  Your function 'auth' has no return type - start by doing that, and enable option strict and option explicit, that will help you find any other places in the code that might have missing types or declarations.

Change function like this is:

```
auth(ByVal cs As String, ByVal pw As String) as Boolean
```

And here is page on those options: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code a little and run it as an VB Application and it works completely. Take a look at the following code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If auth(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text) Then
        MsgBox("Authentication successful!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success")
    Else
        MsgBox("Authentication failed!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Failed")
    End If
End Sub

Public Function auth(ByVal cs As String, ByVal pw As String)
    Select Case cs
        Case "demo1"
            If pw = "100" Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False

            End If

        Case "demo2"
            If pw = "100" Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False

            End If

        Case Else
            Return False

    End Select

End Function
```

End Class

I hope this solves your problem.